# Twisted async request processing

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web, twisted.internet

How can I do async request processing in Twisted like in Node.js?

I wrote sample with Twisted, but my app still waited an answer from long operation(I emulate this with time.sleep).

Also I don't understand how can I use reactor.callLater correct.

This is my sample of twisted app.

```
from twisted.web import server
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
import time

class Hello(Resource):
    def getChild(self, name, request):
        if name == '':
            return self
        print name
        return Resource.getChild(self, name, request)

    def render_GET(self, req):
        d = Deferred()
        reactor.callLater(2, d.callback, None)
        d.addCallback(lambda _: self.say_hi(req))
        return server.NOT_DONE_YET

    def say_hi(self, req):
        req.setHeader("content-type", "text/html")
        time.sleep(5)
        req.write("hello!")
        req.finish()

class Hello2(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, req):
        req.setHeader("content-type", "text/html")
        return "hello2!"

root = Hello()
root.putChild("2", Hello2())
reactor.listenTCP(8080, server.Site(root))
reactor.run()
```

Edit: Now question is how to write a sync code? Please example.

Comment: time.sleep() is blocking call. If you have some heavy processing - try DeferToThread().

Comment: But there are a lot of blocking libs in python. What is recommended usage of such libs?

Comment: Yep - sad but true.
As I mentioned above - you can try to make it with DeferToThread, or search for some async analogs.

Comment: What does "like in Node.js" mean?  Blocking is blocking, Node.js doesn't magically prevent it.

Comment: Hm, I agree. Plus to Node.js is great number of async libraries.

Comment: [An Introduction to Asynchronous Programming and Twisted](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327)

Comment: Here's an [example](https://github.com/zed/txfib) that demonstrates how you could handle blocking CPU intensive code.

Answer (score 4):

You're already doing it... sort of.

Your problem here is that `time.sleep()` is a blocking call, and will therefore make your whole server stop.

If you're using that as a stand-in for something that does network I/O (like `urllib`), the best option is usually to do the I/O with Twisted (like `twisted.web.client.getPage`) rather than to try to do something to the blocking code.  Twisted has lots of client libraries.  These libraries will generally give you a `Deferred`, which you're already handling.

If you're using it as a stand-in for actually waiting, then you can create a `Deferred` which waits with [`deferLater`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.internet.task.deferLater.html).

If you're using it as a stand-in for something CPU intensive that doesn't grab the GIL (like PIL image encoding, or a native XML parser), or an existing native / proprietary I/O layer (like Oracle or MSSQL database bindings) that you'd prefer not to rewrite to use Twisted properly, you can invoke it with [`deferToThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread.html).

However you get your `Deferred`, you're almost set up to handle it.  You just need to adjust `say_hi` to return one:

```
def say_hi(self, req):
    req.setHeader("content-type", "text/html")
    d = getADeferredSomehow()
    def done(result):
        req.write("hello!")
        req.finish()
    return d.addBoth(done)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. time.sleep is just a stub for blocking call. I tried to emulate call of blocking lib(like lots of libs in python) and to learn how can I write non-blocking app.